# Why do I get so little money from the Senators in Disgaea 5?

Tags: disgaea-5

In the Strategy Assembly you can start a bill to receive war funds from the senators. After killing them to get the funds, I get less than 2000 HL. Is this how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Your reward is related to how much approval the senators have towards you.  You are basically cashing in on their disposition.

If you have to force the bill to pass, then they probably don't like you too much to begin with.

Comment: But it's ridiculously hard to get their approval above 1% - isn't force the only way?

Comment: It has always been ridiculously hard to get HL that way.  It's an assembly that nobody ever uses for getting HL.  I actually have no idea what it is used for TBH... :P

Comment: I have at least heard that people use to it find all of the senators that hate you and bribe them into oblivion. This then carries over and eventually you cycle through every single senator and they all love you.

Comment: Oh, that's true.  The War Funds have one of the worst favor modifier but costs little to initiate.  The true goal isn't to get HL though :)  I remember doing that in Disgaea 2 to increase my bill passing chances.